# Multiple jobs using python-crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, cron-task

I am using python-crontab to build a Desktop notification system. However, I can not figure out how to schedule multiple scripts using python-crontab.

Here is what I have to schedule one script:

```
my_user_cron  = CronTab(user=True)
job=my_user_cron.new(command='usr/bin/python3 /Users/Desktop/script.py', comment='script')
job.setall(* * * * *)
my_user_cron.write()
```

If anyone knows how to schedule multiple scripts using this library, please let me know. If you need more information or have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps :

```
cron = CronTab(user='username')

job1 = cron.new(command='python example1.py')

job1.hour.every(2)

job2 = cron.new(command='python example1.py')
job2.every(2).hours()

for item in cron:
    print item

cron.write()
```